# Alternate background color in Listview XAML

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, listview, microsoft-metro

I'm using a listView based on itemTemplate.
So i need in my template to alternate the background color :
 - fist row: white
 - second row:gray
 - third row: white
 - forth: gray

this is my template:

```
     <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemFlight" >
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Background="#28AADB" Margin="2">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=IsArrival, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToImageDisplayConverter}}" Width="30" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
            </Border>
            <Grid Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FlightName}" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  Margin="10" Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockStyle}"/>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArrivalOrDepartDateTime, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeConverter}}"  FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockStyle}"/>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Terminal, Converter={StaticResource StringUpperConverter}}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10"  Visibility="{Binding Path=IsArrival,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityReverseConverter}}" Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CityInfo.Name}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsArrival,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockStyle}"/>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DepartureTime}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockStyle}"/>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CityInfo.Name}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockStyle}"  Visibility="{Binding Path=IsArrival,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityReverseConverter}}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Terminal, Converter={StaticResource StringUpperConverter}}"  Visibility="{Binding Path=IsArrival,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockStyle}"/>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArrivalTime}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockStyle}"/>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="15" Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockStyle}"  Foreground="#EA6A1E" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" />

            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

How Can I do this please??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404539/wpf-alternating-colors-on-a-itemscontrol

Comment: in listview there's no member  AlternationCount="2"

Comment: you need to fire a trigger based on its index. I think a converter will be helpfull for such trigger.

Comment: Related: http://refat38.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/wpf-listview-alternate-row-color/

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I tried this and it works for me.

```
<Window x:Class="TryResponses.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TryResponses"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="MainWindowViewModel" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Background="LightGray" DataContext="{StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex"  Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex"  Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <DataTemplate DataType="system:String">
            <!-- put your data template here -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AlternationCount="2" />
</Grid>
```

I hope this will help.

Regards

Claude

Comment: It did not work for me. Can you please check my question for the same a5t http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990609/give-color-to-alternate-rows-in-listview?noredirect=1#comment38852802_24990609

Comment: This solution works fine. Make sure you set the alternation count on your collection control. I added the style triggers to ListView.ItemContainerStyle on my Listview. Thank you!

Comment: Works well! Thanks.

Comment: This works but now selecting a row gets a very odd look, half the row goes lighter and half doesn't. and it's not clear what is selected

Comment: See my new post below

Answer (score 6):

You should use AlternationCount property and it works on ListBox,ListView or any other control that inherits from ItemsControl. 
The property definition and two examples are included at
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationcount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To view more clearly the selected lines, you can try this : (don't take care about the colors and final render, i've not spent the necessary time to make it sexy)

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:FalseToCollapsedConverter x:Key="FalseToCollapsedConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AlternationCount="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Grid x:Name="line">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ContentControl Content="{Binding .}" Margin="4" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="V" Margin="4" Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem, Mode=FindAncestor}, Converter={StaticResource FalseToCollapsedConverter}}" />
                                <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="#5500FF00" 
                                        BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2"
                                        Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem, Mode=FindAncestor}, Converter={StaticResource FalseToCollapsedConverter}}" />
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex"  Value="0">
                                    <Setter TargetName="line" Property="Background" Value="#CCCCFF" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex"  Value="1">
                                    <Setter TargetName="line" Property="Background" Value="#CCFFCC" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```