# uwp: how to change background color of listview item based on its value?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

Edit: UWP App is not 100% the same like the WPF App.

I have a uwp App with a ListView. In the ListView i use a DataTemplate with the class of Tests. It displays the name of the Test and Points.

What i want to accomplish is that a Trigger !? checks **if the Points are greater than i.e.: 50 and then change the background color** of the ListViewItem to red.

```
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Tests">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"  />
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Points}"  />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternating Colors of rows in ListView in Windows Phone 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607886/alternating-colors-of-rows-in-listview-in-windows-phone-8-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in several ways:

1. Use `ItemContrainerStyleSelector`: [the sample](https://zamjad.wordpress.com/2010/01/01/applying-style-conditionally/) which I found
2. Use `DataTemplateSelector`: [the sample](https://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2012/07/24/data-template-selector-in-windows-8-metro-xaml-app/) which I found
3. Use `Converter`: [the sample](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2011/11/14/null.aspx) which I found describes bool to visibility, but you can change it like you want.

Comment: I used the ItemContainerStyleSelector from the sample and updated the code for uwp apps. Info: in "MyStyleSelector" you have to override the "SelectStyleCore" and not as public but as protected!

Comment: Could you share your solution please?

Answer (score 9):

I was finding it hard to get my listview items to show alternative colours. Finally I managed to do this by assigning a method to the ListView event handler ContainerContentChanging.

[image]

The method assigned to this event gets called when each item gets populated in the listview. This provides a capability to change foreground, background, text, etc for the listview item

```
        private void listViewContentChange(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args) {
            //this method is called for each item while it gets loaded in the listview. Here we are changing background color and text color
            if (args.ItemIndex == 0) {
              //colour for header
              args.ItemContainer.Background = (SolidColorBrush) Application.Current.Resources["grey"];
            } else {
              if (args.ItemIndex % 2 == 0) {
                //lighter colour 
                args.ItemContainer.Background = (SolidColorBrush) Application.Current.Resources["lightblue"];
              } else {
                //Dark colour 
                args.ItemContainer.Background = (SolidColorBrush) Application.Current.Resources["blue"];
              }
            }
```

Comment: This was very helpful for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27621234/3869250

In that example, the poster just checked if it was even or odd, to create alternating colors.

```
if (index % 2 == 0)
{
    ...
}
```

In your case, you could do something like:

```
if(item.Points > 50)
{
    return this.RedBackgroundStyle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[have a look at that full code snippet answer about alternate colors.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47696315/2036103)