# Alternate color for listview item UWP

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a class to color alternate the background of item, but if I delete a item, the background color does not update.
Is there a way to refresh the background color after deleting an item?

The code for alterante color.
class listview:

```
public class AlternatingRowListView : ListView
{
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
        var listViewItem = element as ListViewItem;
        if (listViewItem != null)
        {
            var index = IndexFromContainer(element);

            if (index % 2 == 0)
            {
                listViewItem.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue);
            }
            else
            {
                listViewItem.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

code xaml:

```
<local:AlternatingRowListView x:Name="listview">
        <ListViewItem>item 1</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>item 2</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>item 3</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>item 4</ListViewItem>
        <local:AlternatingRowListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

            </DataTemplate>
        </local:AlternatingRowListView.ItemTemplate>
</local:AlternatingRowListView>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to extend your already extended `AlternatingRowListView` control a bit to achieve what you need.

You can monitor whenever an item gets removed from the list by subscribing to the `VectorChanged` event of the `Items`, and then you just loop through all the *already realized* items **below**(visually) the removed item and change their background colors accordingly.

Something like this would do -

```
public AlternatingRowListView()
{
    DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ListView);

    Items.VectorChanged += OnItemsVectorChanged;
}

private void OnItemsVectorChanged(IObservableVector<object> sender, IVectorChangedEventArgs args)
{
    // When an item is removed from the list...
    if (args.CollectionChange == CollectionChange.ItemRemoved)
    {
        var removedItemIndex = (int)args.Index;

        // We don't really care about the items that are above the deleted one, so the starting index
        // is the removed item's index.
        for (var i = removedItemIndex; i < Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ContainerFromIndex(i) is ListViewItem listViewItem)
            {
                listViewItem.Background = i % 2 == 0 ? 
                    new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
            }
            // If it's null, it means virtualization is on and starting from this index the container
            // is not yet realized, so we can safely break the loop.
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are searching alternate odd/even row colors:

in app.xml

```
<Application
  ...
  <Application.Resources>
    <AlternateColorConverterx:Key="AlternateColorConverter" />
   ...
  </Application.Resources>
```

generate a new class namely AlternateColorConverter.cs
(modify your hex colors.)

```
  class AlternateColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static int idx_=-1;
    private static int odd_=0;
    private static int idx(int offset)
    {
        int idx_before = idx_;
        idx_ = (idx_ + 1) % (offset);

        if (idx_ < idx_before) odd_=(odd_+1)%2;
        return odd_;
    }

    public static Color GetColorFromHex(string hexString)
    {
        Color x = (Color)XamlBindingHelper.ConvertValue(typeof(Color), hexString);
        return x;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        int param = System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter);
        return new SolidColorBrush(ColorUtils.GetColorFromHex((idx(param) == 0) ? "#F24C27" : "#FBBA42"));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and in yourpage.xml.cs :
(where ConverterParameter(offset) depends on column count. usually 2)

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="20"/>
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="Models:YourObservableArray">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="180*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource AlternateColorConverter},ConverterParameter=2}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0"  Margin="0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Field1}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource AlternateColorConverter},ConverterParameter=2}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0"  Margin="0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Field2}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: sample code is from my uwp project (windows IOT on raspberrypi3). you can check my project on my github project namely portoschool