# Alternative color for listview items

Tags: c++, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I have below listview in my xaml file. It's bound with a platform collection. Which contains warnings and error messages. The textblock foreground color is set to red. I need to set different color for different messages. How can i set different color for various messages?

```
<ListView x:Name="mylist" Width="578" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="White" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Errors}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <TextBlock Foreground="Red" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35346001/uwp-how-to-change-background-color-of-listview-item-based-on-its-value

Answer (score 0):

> The textblock foreground color is set to red. I need to set different color for different messages.

You could use [`IValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter) interface to approach, use converter class to converter different message type to different `SolidBrush` for  Textblock `Foreground`. You could refer the follow ColorConverter.

```
public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (Boolean.Parse(value.ToString()))
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }
        else
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<Page.Resources>
        <local:ColorConverter x:Key="Converter"/>
</Page.Resources>

       ......

<TextBlock Text="{Binding info}" Foreground="{Binding messageType,Converter={StaticResource Converter}}"/>
```