# Sorting and alternating ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I don't know how to implement functions to my XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationLAB.HighScore"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplicationLAB"
        xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="HighScore" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedItems" Source="{Binding items}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Result"/>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListView Margin="10" Name="lvDataBinding" ItemsSource ="{Binding items}" >
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        <TextBlock Text="  " />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Result}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and C#

```
   public partial class HighScore : Window
    {
        public HighScore()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<User> items = new List<User>();
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe", Result = 42 });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe", Result = 39 });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Result = 13 });
        }
    }
    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Result { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Name + "   " + this.Result;
        }
    }
}
```

Tried to implement `CollectionView` sorting but it's not working, what should I change?

Second thing is that I wanted to alternate background color and font color. I tried also to implement function for alternating from this example: [Alternate background color in Listview XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796342/alternate-background-color-in-listview-xaml). But I don't understand `Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0"` and

```
<DataTemplate DataType="system:String">
            <!-- put your data template here -->
</DataTemplate>
```

How should I implement this?

Comment: Please be more specific than "it's not working". The code you posted doesn't appear valid: there's no data context, nor anything with an `items` property to bind to, and you don't appear to be using the `CollectionViewSource` anyway. What _exactly_ does the code do when you run it, and how _exactly_ is that different from what you want? As for the `AlternationIndex` question, you should post a new question with a [mcve] that shows how you tried to use it, along with a _precise_ description of what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really clear from your question what specifically you're having trouble with. However, the code you posted is wrong in a number of ways:

1. You don't set a data context nor specify binding sources explicitly.
2. There is nothing that even *has* an `items` property to bind to.
3. You declare, but do not use, the `CollectionViewSource`, so it would have no effect in any case.

There is also nothing in the code example that shows how you tried to use `AlternationIndex`, so it's impossible to say what you did wrong.

All that said, the basic ideas are simple enough. Since you found the example regarding `AlternationIndex`, I'll take as granted that you also did so for the `CollectionViewSource` part of your question and simply failed to understand those examples. I am including below a version of your code that addresses all of the issues I mention above, as well as shows one possible way to use `AlternationIndex` to produce formatting differences per-line in your output:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestSO37246528SortAndAlternationIndex.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Name="mainWindow">

  <Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedItems" Source="{Binding items, ElementName=mainWindow}">
      <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Result"/>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name"/>
      </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <ListView Margin="10" Name="lvDataBinding"
              ItemsSource ="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedItems}}"
              AlternationCount="2">
      <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
          <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
            </Trigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
          <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
        </Style>
      </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBlock Text="  " />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Result}" FontWeight="Bold" />
          </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C#:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<User> items { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        items = new List<User>();
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe", Result = 42 });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe", Result = 39 });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Result = 13 });
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The `User` class is as before, so I haven't bothered to include it here.

You'll note in the above the following changes:

1. I gave the window a name, so that I could use it as a binding source.
2. I moved the local variable `items` out of the constructor and made it a property in the class. Note that since I did nothing to produce change notifications, it's also critical that the property be set and the list contents are populated before the `InitializeComponent()` method.
3. Rather than binding to the original list, I bind using the `CollectionViewSource` as the binding source, thus ensuring that the `ListView` uses the view from the `CollectionViewSource`.

Please carefully compare the above with your original code, so that you can understand how each of the specific problems was fixed. If you have any questions, please feel free to ask. Be sure to state in clear, precise terms what *specifically* you're having trouble understanding.

Comment: Okey, I understand more, but somehow it still does not shows the results in the window. I copy your code to be sure if I did not any mistake and still there is no one person on the list.

Comment: Okey! found simple issue, THANKS! :) It take me lots of time and diggind, and you did it so fast! :)