# Windows Phone 8: Alternating colors on a ItemsControl

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to alternate color of items in ItemsControl based on item index - odd or even. As I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404539/wpf-alternating-colors-on-a-itemscontrol) it is pretty easy to do, but looks like ItemsControl for Windows Phone doesn't have AlternationCount property.

Is there any alternatives to AlternationCount property or workarounds to achieve required behavior?

[ItemsControl reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could inherit the ItemsControl class and override PrepareContainerForItemOverride. There you can calculate the AlternationIndex e.g. by using ItemsControl.IndexFromContainer. Now you can apply a specific Style to the container or set an attached property.

Answer (score 1):

Use data template selector, you will find useful sample [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/implementing-windows-phone-7-datatemplateselector-and-customdatatemplateselector)

Comment: This is not a solution because it relies on Model data as item Type which should be specified, but not on item index in ItemsControl.