# How can I display rows with alternating aligning?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to achieve something similar with this image:

[image: Alternating rows.]

Rows with alternating alignment - aligned to the left when the row's index is even, aligned to the right when the row's index is uneven.

I tried to use `ListBox` of `ListBox`, binding with `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Circle>>`. Should I bind the `Margin` property of the second `ListBox` in order to achieve the alternating alignment?

```
<ListBox
  Name="OuterListBox"
  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
  VerticalAlignment="Center"
  Background="White"
  BorderThickness="0"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Board}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <ListBox
          Name="InnerListBox"
          HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalAlignment}"
          Background="Transparent"
          BorderThickness="0"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ChangeListViewItemHighlight}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          PreviewKeyDown="InnerListBox_PreviewKeyDown">
          <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Ellipse
                  Width="{Binding Size}"
                  Height="{Binding Size}"
                  Cursor="Hand"
                  Fill="{Binding Background}" />
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: It might be easier to accomplish this by the way you format the objects in the ListBox.Items. Perhaps inserting something that is 1/2 width at the beginning of alternating rows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use AlternationIndex in ItemsControls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567778/how-to-use-alternationindex-in-itemscontrols)

Comment: Is there a fixed number of rows?

Comment: @james.lee yes, also the number of columns is a fixed number

Comment: @TerryTyson It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your requirements, I assume from the example you provided that:

- There are multiple rows.
- Each row has the same number of items (circles, here 5).
- All items (circles) have the same size.

This way, you can achieve the desired behavior with built-in functionality in a few steps.

- Change the `ItemsPanel` in the inner `ListBox` to display the items (circles) horizontally (as a row)
- Set an [`AlternationCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationcount?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Controls_ItemsControl_AlternationCount) of `2` to the outer `ListBox`, so there are two alternation indices.
- Create an item container style for the out `ListBox`, which sets a `Padding` (or `Margin` if you want) of half the width of your circle items on the left for [`AlternationIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationindex?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Controls_ItemsControl_AlternationIndex) `0` and the same on the right otherwise. You can create an instance of the already existing [`AlternationConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.alternationconverter?view=net-5.0) to define the `Padding`s.

In this example, the paddings are fixed size (for me circle have a size of `50`, so the padding is `25`). You could also create a custom value converter to make this more dynamic, binding the real `Size`.

```
<ListBox
   Name="OuterListBox"
   AlternationCount="2"
   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
   VerticalAlignment="Center"
   Background="White"
   BorderThickness="0"
   ItemsSource="{Binding Board}">
   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
         <Style.Resources>
            <AlternationConverter x:Key="AlternationPaddingConverter">
               <Thickness Right="25"/>
               <Thickness Left="25"/>
            </AlternationConverter>
         </Style.Resources>
         <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{Binding (ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource AlternationPaddingConverter}}"/>
      </Style>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Grid>
            <ListBox
               Name="InnerListBox"
               Background="Transparent"
               BorderThickness="0"
               ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ChangeListViewItemHighlight}"
               ItemsSource="{Binding}"
               PreviewKeyDown="InnerListBox_PreviewKeyDown">
               <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                     <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
               </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
               <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                     <Ellipse
                        Width="{Binding Size}"
                        Height="{Binding Size}"
                        Cursor="Hand"
                        Fill="{Binding Background}" />
                  </DataTemplate>
               </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

[image: Circle board with rows that have an alternating padding.]

---

> Additional question: how can I remove the highlight of the selected line?

In this simple case, you could use an `ItemsControl` as outer control instead of a `ListBox`. It has no selection. However, you have to style the `ContentPresenter` and use `Margin` then.

```
<ItemsControl
   Name="OuterListBox"
   AlternationCount="2"
   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
   VerticalAlignment="Center"
   Background="White"
   BorderThickness="0"
   ItemsSource="{Binding Board}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
         <Style.Resources>
            <AlternationConverter x:Key="AlternationPaddingConverter">
               <Thickness Right="25"/>
               <Thickness Left="25"/>
            </AlternationConverter>
         </Style.Resources>
         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding (ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource AlternationPaddingConverter}}"/>
      </Style>
   </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Grid>
            <ListBox
               Name="InnerListBox"
               Background="Transparent"
               BorderThickness="0"
               ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ChangeListViewItemHighlight}"
               ItemsSource="{Binding}"
               PreviewKeyDown="InnerListBox_PreviewKeyDown">
               <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                     <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
               </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
               <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                     <Ellipse
                        Width="{Binding Size}"
                        Height="{Binding Size}"
                        Cursor="Hand"
                        Fill="{Binding Background}" />
                  </DataTemplate>
               </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Additional question: how can I remove the highlight of the selected line?